# Is it possible to declare the <template> inside a custom element? how?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to declare `<template>` inside a js custom element. Inside the template are `<style>` and `<slot>` tags. The content do not get replaced when I use them in the page.

my code looks like this:

```
(function(){
    class SampleElement extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

            const template = document.createElement('template');
            template.innerHTML = `
                <slot name="sample">text</slot>
            `;
            document.body.appendChild(template);
        }
    }

    customElements.define('sample-element', SampleElement);
})();
```

and in my HTML:

```
<sample-element>
    <div slot="sample">new text</div>
</sample-element>
```

How can I replace the slot value in the template inside the custom element?

Comment: you are attaching the template to the body element, and not to your custom element shadow root. Attaching the template will not give you access to the slot, you have to clone the template's content, as the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, I assume you want to use the innerHTML of a template as the template of your custom element.

```js
(function () {
 
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  
  template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      :host {
        display:block;
      }
    </style>

   <div>
    <slot name="replace">I am the fallback</slot>
   </div>
  `;
  
  
  class El extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      // attach the shadow root to our element
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      // using the template innerHTML as the custom element scaffold/template
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    }
  }
  
  
  customElements.define('my-el', El);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <my-el></my-el>
 <my-el>
   <span slot="replace">I am the override</span>
 </my-el>
  
</body>
</html>
```